# Why does the react-sortable-hoc basic example fail to compile with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-sortable-hoc

Here is the basic example from the [react-sortable-hoc webpage](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) =>
  <li>{value}</li>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
  };
  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
}

render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I had to alter the code above very slightly to fit with typescript import syntax, and the screenshot below shows the errors I am unsure how to fix:

[image]

Here is the code corresponding to the above screenshot:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) =>
  <li>{value}</li>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
  };
  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I don't know how to parse the error text of these errors. Since the project has 5k+ stars on GitHub, I assume I have some sort of config issue, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

These are the two remaining errors:

1.

> [ts] Property 'items' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes

2.

> [ts] Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes

The error text reads to me like it's not picking up the component wrapping syntax up correctly, but I am unfamiliar with this syntax myself so I'm not sure if I've diagnosed the problem correctly or how to fix it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @Rob thank you for this comment. I have added the corresponding code. I will keep the image for a visual indication of where the errors are in the source code. The error text is already in the body of the question

Comment: @BlackSheep I just tried your code and it works form me. lastest packages in a clean solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code in the basic example in the docs is JavaScript.

Here is the basic example converted to TypeScript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { arrayMove, SortableContainer, SortableElement } from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}: {value: string}) =>
  <li>{value}</li>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}: {items: string[]}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends React.Component<{}, {items: string[]}> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
    }
  }
  public render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
  private onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}: {oldIndex: number, newIndex: number}) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This solves only half of the problem, at least in current version. Typing props won't prevent an error when using the component. This is what I had to do:
`const SortableItem = SortableElement<{ value: string }>(({ value }: { value: string })` alternatively `const SortableItem: React.ComponentClass<SortableElementProps & { value: string }> = SortableElement(Item)`

Answer (score 5):

You should specify aditional types for sortable container and sortable item, it will fix your problem:

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove, SortableContainerProps, SortableElementProps} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem: React.ComponentClass<SortableElementProps & { value: string }, any> = SortableElement(({ value }: { value: string }) =>
  <li>{value}</li>
);

const SortableList: React.ComponentClass<SortableContainerProps & { items: string[] }, any> = SortableContainer(({ items }: { items: string[] }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value: any, index: number) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
  };
  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}: {oldIndex: number, newIndex: number}) => {
    this.setState({
      items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone needs the code for the optional drag handle I am using mui with ts, I have also included the sample of the 'packageData' let me know in case u need to see the interface?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  SortableContainer,
  SortableElement,
  SortableHandle
} from 'react-sortable-hoc';
import arrayMove from 'array-move';
import { packageData } from '../../data/packagesData';
import { List } from '@material-ui/core';
import ListItem from '../../components/UI/ListItem/ListItem';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DragIndicator';
import { PackageResAdmin } from '../../ts/apiTs';

const DragHandle = SortableHandle(() => <EditIcon />);

const SortableItem = SortableElement(
  ({ id, galleryId, translations }: PackageResAdmin) => (
    <ListItem
      id={id}
      children={<DragHandle />}
      galleryId={galleryId}
      translations={translations}
    />
  )
);
const SortableContainerWrapper = SortableContainer(
  ({ children }: { children: {}[] }) => {
    return <List>{children}</List>;
  }
);

class DndComponent extends Component {
  state = { packageData };

  private onSortEnd = ({
    oldIndex,
    newIndex
  }: {
    oldIndex: number;
    newIndex: number;
  }) => {
    this.setState({
      packageData: arrayMove(this.state.packageData, oldIndex, newIndex)
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <SortableContainerWrapper onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} useDragHandle>
        {this.state.packageData.map((res, index) => (
          <SortableItem
            key={`item-${index}`}
            index={index}
            id={res.id}
            galleryId={res.galleryId}
            translations={res.translations}
          />
        ))}
      </SortableContainerWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default DndComponent;


export const packageData: PackageResAdmin[] = [


{
    galleryId: 1,
    id: 1,
    translations: {
      [Language.CS]: {
        additionalInfo: 'additionalInfo',
        content: 'content',
        language: Language.CS,
        parentId: 1,
        title: 'eden'
      },
      [Language.EN]: {
        additionalInfo: 'additionalInfo',
        content: 'content',
        language: Language.EN,
        parentId: 1,
        title: 'one'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    galleryId: 1,
    id: 2,
    translations: {
      [Language.CS]: {
        additionalInfo: 'additionalInfo',
        content: 'content',
        language: Language.CS,
        parentId: 1,
        title: 'dva'
      },
      [Language.EN]: {
        additionalInfo: 'additionalInfo',
        content: 'content',
        language: Language.EN,
        parentId: 1,
        title: 'two'
      }
    }
  }
];
```